# Google Cloud Spanner insert is very slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am new to Cloud Spanner. My Cloud Spanner instance is a single node instance (as I am doing POC). I am doing simple insert. However, it returns the result after 5 to 8 seconds, although it shows `Time elapsed: 1.16 secs`.

I am clueless as to why. Also, if I go with the time that Google shows, 1.16 seconds for simple insert is still too much. A benchmark that was performed by couple of people showcase the average time taken is around `16 ms` to `80 ms`.

Here's my insert statement:

```
Insert into SP_DATAFLOW_PER_INCR (PER_NATL_ID, DQ_PER_NATL_ID_FLG, PER_FRST_NM, PER_MID_NM, PER_LST_NM, PER_MTRNL_LST_NM, PER_BRTH_DT, DQ_PER_BRTH_DT_FLG, PER_SEX_CD, DQ_PER_SEX_CD_FLG, PER_CELL_NUM, DQ_PER_CELL_NUM_FLG, PER_DTH_IND, PER_EMAIL_ADR_TXT, DQ_PER_EMAIL_ADR_TXT_FLG, PER_ED_LVL_CD, REC_STRT_TS, REC_END_TS, CUR_REC_IND, loadingdate) 
values('00000000000000666971', false, 'DE', 'DIOS', 'DIAZ', 'JUAN', '1906-08-11', false, 'M', false, 'No Data', false, false, '', true, '','2019-12-09 03:51:06.249454 UTC', null, true, '2019-12-09');
```

- Am I doing anything wrong?
- Can someone please help me understand    this? Google documentation
  does not mention anything on this    behavior.

Comment: How exactly are you executing the insert? Are you using one of the client libraries (e.g. the Java client, Go client, ...)? Could it be that your timing includes the time it takes to initialize the client library, opening a session, etc.? Or are you using some other tool to execute the insert?

Comment: I am using GCP web UI

Comment: Could you provide the scheme of you DB to reproduce your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Running queries through the GCP console or gcloud command line is expected to be a little slow. For a simple insert, there are some overheads such as creating a [session](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions) which can be expensive.

If you want to evaluate the performance of Cloud Spanner, you should use the client libraries (see [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/tutorials)).